# Boot process "scheduler"

Tags: scheduler

Where in the boot process does the "scheduler"  get created and when created how can its instructions be accessed?

Comment: is this homework? the answer to this depends on the operating system in question.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the OS you use, but several things should be clear:

- before the first switch to userland
- before any kernel threads are started or any other multi-programming (multi-tasking) is done

Obviously that is relatively early in the boot process.

What exactly do you mean by *"how can its instructions be accessed?"*?

Answer (score 0):

the default scheduler is set in kernel config :
adrian@adrian: ~ $ grep cfq /boot/config-2.6.36.2-desktop-2mnb 
CONFIG_DEFAULT_IOSCHED="cfq"

at boot time you can do in the kernel line as example:
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-8.el5 ro root=/dev/sda2 **elevator=deadline**

Comment: ...assuming the system is running the Linux kernel. **Also you are confusing between the CPU scheduler and disk-IO scheduler!** :-)

Comment: you are totally right! i assumed the io as, with the advent of ssds, this was the most common tuning :) .. for cpu scheduling a good start would be https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/ .. also various distros have performance tuning guides with useful information.